# Is there any way to check Google Form Owner, who created the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-docs

I am looking for a possible way to check and basically track the google form owner. Is there any way we can track the email attached to that Google form. I am working with a client but not directly. I am looking for the client's email to contact him through directly. He owns the google form which the broker shared to me. This is only for legal purposes. Or somehow we can track the spreadsheet which captures the google form responses. Thanks

I have inspected the google form, but I have got no such response.

Comment: What have you tried so far in terms of code. Please share what you can.